# How to get Viewport Height Between Bars on Mobile? (React)

Tags: android, css, ios, reactjs, safari

I would like to know the exact device viewport height between the top bar and bottom bar on IOS, Android, Safari, Chrome, etc. Is this possible?

Top bar meaning search bar, and bottom bar meaning nav bar.

```
const visibleMobileHeight = viewportHeight - topBarHeight - bottomBarHeight;
```

[image]

[image]

I would like my application to stay between these bars no matter what, in all situations, all scenarios.

vw, vh doesnt work because that gives the entire screen size including bars.

Currently, my application is obscured by the bars, it's kind of annoying lol. If you use 100% instead of vh and vw, the application will not render. Position fixed causes a glitch when rotating, the bottom bar forces the content up and leaves an extra space at the bottom.

Example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-pine-td7ee?file=/src/App.js)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No real solution right now. But I suggest taking a read of https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4329 where it is agreed that some new units (svh and dvh) will be added  which I think is for your requirement.

Comment: @Alohci I guess I better learn native then :(